# The difference when creating a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am a newbie. NO experience aside from a few weeks of coding.
I want to create a list (I use IDLE txt editor). 
When creating a list I type

```
animals = ['cat, dog, cow, bird']
```

When I try the same thing but the only difference is putting each element in quotes. ie:

```
['cat' , 'dog' , 'cow' , 'bird']
```

They print:

1. with the quotes at the end
2. each element between quotes

What is the difference if there is any?

Comment: How many elements do you want your list to have?  The 1st example creates a list containing one element, a long string containing commas.  The 2nd creates a list from 4 strings.

Comment: "They both just print 1." What prints 1? Where is the `print()`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the "1" was just formatting in the question...

Answer (score 2):

In your example one you have a list with one element, this element is a string, enclosed by quote.

In your second example, you have a list with several elements inside, all of them are string.

Now try to play with both examples you will see. Iterate your lists with a for loop, index them...

Answer (score 1):

- `animals = ['cat, dog, cow, bird']` creates a list with one element which happens to be a sentence; try `print(type(animals))` and `len(animals)` to verify.
- `['cat' , 'dog' , 'cow' , 'bird']` creates a list with four elements.

In general, elements of a list are separated by a comma but in your first case since you start with a quote it is considered as a string (single element) till such time you close the quotes even though there are commas in between.

Answer (score 1):

They both are lists.

`animals = ['cat, dog, cow, bird']` This is a list of one element with one string, there are one pair of single quotes.

`animals = ['cat' , 'dog' , 'cow' , 'bird']` This is a list of four elements, since there are **four** pairs of single quotes.

The easier way to understand the difference is by executing the following:

```
for a in ['cat, dog, cow, bird']:
    print(a)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
cat, dog, cow, bird
```

**AND**

```
for a in ['cat' , 'dog' , 'cow' , 'bird']:
    print(a)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
cat
dog
cow
bird
```

Answer (score -1):

Good question. Let's start by breaking down the contents of the list, in something closer to the machine code.

The first one:

```
[0xFFFAAAA0]
```

There only *one* element in this list: The string `'cat, dog, cow, bird'`. `0xFFFAAAA0` is the *memory location (or reference), to the contiguous block of memory that represent that string*. Those contiguous blocks of memory (8 bits wide for a character, otherwise known as a byte, as far as I know) will have the actual characters that represent the string, starting at the memory location `0xFFFAAAA0`:

```
99 | 97 | 116 | 44 | 32 …
```

Which, to a human, looks like:

```
c | a | t | , | d …
```

The second one:

```
[0xFFFAAA00, 0xFFFAABA0, 0xFFFCABA0, 0xFFDAAAA0]
```

Is the same as before. At 0xFFFAAA00:

```
99 | 97 | 116 (c | a | t)
```

At 0xFFFAABA0:

```
32 | 100 | 111 (d | o | g)
```

The comma goes away because it's not actual a character, but something Python uses to separate list elements (otherwise known as a *token*).

Why do the strings have the memory locations they do? Great question! That gets into how C allocates memory, which is something I don't have experience with - but you're a good programmer and scientist for thinking about it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is simply not an accurate description of the CPython internals. In any case, I think the OP is asking a much more basic question.